# When displaying a PDF inside an embed tag, is there any way to disable or remove a button from the toolbar?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, adobe, embed

I am using an embed tag to display a pdf on a webpage, and I have been trying to find a way to hide or disable the Rotate Counterclockwise button on the toolbar.

[image: Rotate Counterclockwise button on pdf viewer toolbar]

I have tried a few solutions so far, but it doesn't seem like I am able to target the html inside the embed #document with JavaScript or CSS.  I discovered I can append url parameters to the source url such as "#toolbar=0" to hide the toolbar completely, but I need to hide just one button.